# Dataframe add buisness days according to multiple features

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-manipulation

I have a quite big data-frame with different products, locations, sold_value and the according date.
I want to manipulate the DF in the way that each product for its according location gets dates values according to buisness day freq. As next step i want the sold_value if sold on same date (still according to product and its location) gets added to each other. So that basically each product with its according location has a buisness day freq with sold_value.

I tried multiple things already,
at first i tied just to manipulate the DF with groupby....
as next i tried to make new dataframes for each product with its according location add the bday frq and .sum the sold_value according to date after that merging all the DFs but it wont quite work.

as a side fact there are hundreds of locations and products so i cant hard code their values

PS.: Thanks for Help

The DF:

| product | location | date | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 01-01-2022 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 04-01-2022 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 01-01-2022 | 5 |
| 2 | 1 | 01-01-2022 | 4 |
| 2 | 1 | 01-01-2022 | 3 |
| 2 | 2 | 01-01-2022 | 1 |

My wanted output:

| product | location | date | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 01-01-2022 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 02-01-2022 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 03-01-2022 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 04-01-2022 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 01-01-2022 | 5 |
| 2 | 1 | 01-01-2022 | 7 |
| 2 | 2 | 01-01-2022 | 1 |

Comment: Hi, please post a minimal example dataframe of what you have, and what you expect as output. The example should be copy-pasteable (python code) to make it easier for people to help you.

Comment: its under the visualisation link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First aggregate `sum` for column `value`:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], dayfirst=True)

df = df.groupby(['ct','location','date'], as_index=False)['value'].sum()
print (df)
   ct  location       date  value
0   1         1 2022-01-01      1
1   1         1 2022-01-04      1
2   1         2 2022-01-01      5
3   2         1 2022-01-01      7
4   2         2 2022-01-01      1
```

Then add `0` days per days in lambda function with [`Series.asfreq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.asfreq.html):

```
f = lambda x: x.asfreq('D', fill_value=0)
df1 = df.set_index('date').groupby(['ct','location'])['value'].apply(f).reset_index()
print (df1)
   ct  location       date  value
0   1         1 2022-01-01      1
1   1         1 2022-01-02      0
2   1         1 2022-01-03      0
3   1         1 2022-01-04      1
4   1         2 2022-01-01      5
5   2         1 2022-01-01      7
6   2         2 2022-01-01      1
```

If want use business days ouput is different:

```
f = lambda x: x.asfreq('B', fill_value=0)
df2 = df.set_index('date').groupby(['ct','location'])['value'].apply(f).reset_index()
print (df2)
   ct  location       date  value
0   1         1 2022-01-03      0
1   1         1 2022-01-04      1
```